# Code to copy only filtered data

Tags: vba, excel

This code works for the most part but it copies all data in the data set rather than just the data that has been filtered. The filter is working correctly when I step through it but it copies everything. What am I  doing wrong?

```
Sub Auto_Filter()

Dim RNG As Range
Dim Open_Jobs_Report As Worksheet
Set Open_Jobs_Report = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Jobs Report")
Dim Calculations As Worksheet
Set Calculations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations")
Dim PersonResponsible As Range
Dim Violations As Range
Dim CLM1 As Long
Dim CLM2 As Long


    With Sheets("Open Jobs Report")
        Set RNG = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
        RNG.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="<>"

        CLM1 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Person Responsible").Column
        Set PersonResponsible = .Range(.Cells(1, CLM1), .Cells(1, CLM1).End(xlDown))
        CLM2 = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Violations").Column
        Set Violations = .Range(.Cells(1, CLM2), .Cells(1, CLM2).End(xlDown))

    End With


    Calculations.Range("A:A").Value = PersonResponsible.Value
    Calculations.Range("B:B").Value = Violations.Value




    With Sheets("Open Jobs Report")

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData '<= Fix this

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, replace the ranges with any other ranges you need to copy data from.

```
dim r As Range 
dim x(1 to 100,1 to 1) 
i = 1 
   For Each r In PersonResponsible.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        x(i,1) = r :i = i + 1 
   Next
   Calculations.Range("A1").resize(i-1).value = x
```

Edit:
Maybe something like this,

```
PersonResponsible.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Calculations.Range("A1")
```

Comment: I would rather avoid a loop if I can. This used to work but I made some changes and I am not sure what would cause it to start including hidden fields.

Comment: @TonyP, double comment.

Comment: @TonyP, `Calculations` worksheet in your code is not set. That would throw the error you speak of. My bad. I see you have it set within the dim statements.

Comment: Isn't it set with                                                                          Set Calculations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations")?

Comment: @TonyP. yes it is, I realized after I posted that comment. Can you temporarly create a sheet and replace the `calculations` sheet in the code? ie, `Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`

Answer (score 0):

use `Advanced Filter` with something like this:

```
Dim rCriteria as Range
Set rCriteria = [Headears of columns you want]

RNG.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= rCriteria, _  
                        CopyToRange:=[where you want], Unique:=True
```